# Cannot connect to remote host with mstsc.exe

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

One of our users tries to connect from home to one of our servers through mstsc.exe, but is unable to do so. Each time she tries to connect, she gets a messagebox stating "the computer was unable to establish a connection to the remote host", "please try again etc...".

When I look in the event viewer for remote desktop, I see a warning for each failed attempt, with an error ID of 1041.

First I ran Windows Update and specifically checked KB2574819, KB2592687, KB2830477 and KB 2923545 (culprits in the past for similar situations), but no luck.

I found some articles stating that TSPrint was the cause: I uninstalled TSprint, installed it again, and deinstalled it once more. No change.

After a lot of Googling, I found the following advice to change a policy: Computer Configuration->Windows Settings->Security Settings – Network security:LAN Manager authentication level: set to "Send NTLMV2 response only”.

Since this is a Windows 10 Home edition, I could not change the policy, so I downloaded a tool to change the policy nonetheless. No change.

I upgraded the laptop to Windows 10 Pro and tried again - no change. Downgraded again, tried again - no change.

The above solutions (updates, TSPrint or policies) did not succeed and after a day of trying to figure out why this laptop won't connect (yet hundreds of others have no trouble), I have no more ideas left.

Does anybody have any suggestions on what to try next? Thanks in advance!

Joe

Comment: Did you verify the network traffic actually arrives and/or is sent?

Comment: Yes - Client and server do communicate with one another.

Comment: With RDP or with a different protocol? There could be any number of obstacles like firewalls on the PC or at an ISP or the like. I suggest you use Wireshark on both ends of the connection to verify data actually travels both ways.

Comment: I looked at Wireshark on the laptop and saw messages being passed both ways, although I'm not sure about the protocol. The laptop is connected via wifi on our guest network, so there is no ISP in between. Firewall is not an issue, there are 100s identical laptops which do work and who pass through the same firewall. Local Windows firewall was disabled, as was all other possibly intervening software (Bullguard for example). Installing software on the server is not an option, as this will not be allowed.